# How to disable unsafe scripts from executing in chrome beta which supports CSP

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

I am using the latest beta version of chrome (which claims to support CSP) and I have a web page where users can enter comments and the comments then gets stored to a DB and is then retrieved and displayed on the same webpage.

A User can enter a Javascript as a comment (with the script tag) and when that is retrieved from DB , it gets executed (say a alert). CSP says that such things will not be allowed.

What should i do to get this feature(of disabling unsafe javascripts from executing) of google chrome beta working.

Currently If i enter a javascript comment, it executes as expected.

Comment: You are referring to http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html which is meant to prevent cross-site scripting. Which has nothing to do with scripts intermingled within webpage output because you failed to escape it.

Comment: i dont think so, it clearly says inline Javascript will not be allowed

Comment: Better reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution

Use chrome dev version 28.
Inline Javascript is by default disabled

go to chrome://flags/ to change these flags

Answer (score 0):

From the [page @mario linked](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html):

> In order to mitigate a large class of potental cross-site scripting
>   issues, Chrome's **extension** system has incorporated the general concept
>   of Content Security Policy (CSP) . This introduces some fairly strict
>   policies that will make **extensions** more secure by default, and
>   provides you with the ability to create and enforce rules governing
>   the types of content that can be loaded and executed by your
>   **extensions** and applications.

Emphasis on extensions added since it's what answers your questions - it only applies to extensions, not to regular web pages. There are [many web pages out there with a valid reason for accepting Javascript postbacks](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: chrome://flags/  lets you set some stuff like these,so this can be disallowed